# Why ajax getting the error from php file?

Tags: ajax, php

hi i use to send a mail in contact form using ajax passing values to php file called test.php all are working fine.

code in test.php

```
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
     {

        echo "mail sent";

     }
     else
     {
        echo "no mail sent";
     }
```

Ajax working fine when the mail sent i'm getting `mail sent` message  when the mail is not sent i should get `no mail sent` . but i'm not getting that alone i'm getting bunch of error code

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 551 User not local. We don't relay in E:\wamp1\wamp\www \test.php on line <i>42</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0007</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>275552</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp1\wamp\www\wp_twentythirteen\wp-admin\admin-ajax.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\admin-ajax.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.2273</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>20765536</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>do_action(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp1\wamp\www\wp_twentythirteen\wp-admin\admin-ajax.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\admin-ajax.php<b>:</b>72</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.2273</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>20767104</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.call-user-func-array' target='_new'>call_user_func_array</a>
(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp1\wamp\www\wp_twentythirteen\wp-includes\plugin.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\plugin.php<b>:</b>406</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>4</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.2273</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>20767136</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>contact_ajax(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp1\wamp\www\wp_twentythirteen\wp-includes\plugin.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\plugin.php<b>:</b>406</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>5</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.2273</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>20767312</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.mail' target='_new'>mail</a>
(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp1\wamp\www \test.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\test.php<b>:</b>42</td></tr>
</table></font>
"no mail sent"
```

In last line am getting this `no mail sent` message. Why is these happening.i want no mail sent message alone. can anybody help

Comment: What is the code on line `42` in `test.php` file?

Comment: Are you running this script locally?

Comment: yes,i have a mail server in local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide that error message using `@` in front mail function:

`if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))`

Comment: @sun: If you're aware that an error might occur and you really don't care (because you're already checking for it), I'd say this is OK. Just don't go around slapping @'s on things willy nilly.

Answer (score 2):

yes, it seems the user isnot allowed to send the email. if you read the error properly it says the same.

```
Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 551 User not local. We don't relay in E:\wamp1\wamp\www \test.php on line 42
```

Read this post @ http://www.webmaster-talk.com/php-forum/60248-smtp-server-response-551-a.html
This should get you going.

Also, adding '@' before the mail function as suggested by many would only ignores the warning. It would not make email function work if a email server isnot set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with rather `try` and `catch`

```
try {
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "mail sent";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error =  'Caught exception: '.  $e->getMessage();
    error_log($error);
    echo "no mail sent";
}
```

Comment: am getting bunch of errors with `mail sent` at last line..any condition missing?

Comment: `mail()` does not throw exceptions. It returns true on success (successful delivery to mail server, this does not mean that the mail has been received by the intended recipient) and false on failure. Using a try-catch won't help. Since no exceptions are thrown, there is nothing to catch.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on localhost (your comptuer) and you are developing this script you can either setup a mail server or use a debug mail function as a wrapper for mail() for your script, where the function accepts all of the same arguments as mail() but does not actually call mail() (instead, it could print the info to the screen or a text file for example).

Then, when you are ready to put the system online, you could modify the function to call mail().

The mail server needs a user login and password for SMTP authentication.

Which means you should contact your webhost as they should provide a working configuration by default (or instructions to obtain such a configuration).

Alternatively you could use PEAR to sort out your problems.